# simplyfing a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I don't know how to get from the left side of the equation to the right side.

$$ \cos x\; \cos2x+\sin x\; \sin2x=\cos x $$

How can I do it? which equations to use?

P.S How can I simplify this?

$$ \cos x\; \cos3x+\sin x\; \sin3x $$

Thanks

Comment: $cos(A+B)=cos(A)cos(B)-sin(A)sin(B)$ and note that $cos(-A)=cos(A)$ and $sin(-A)=-sin(A)$

Comment: Does the music $\cos(a-b)=something$ remembers something to you ?

Comment: To learn it read loudly this formula 10 times:
$$ \cos( cat - mouse ) = \cos (cat) \cos(mouse) + \sin(cat) \sin (mouse) $$
this formula another 10 times:
$$  \cos (cat) \cos(mouse) + \sin(cat) \sin (mouse) = \cos( cat - mouse ) $$

Answer (score 1):

We will need the double angle identities for sine and cosine:
\begin{align*}
\sin(2x) & = 2\sin x\cos x\\
\cos(2x) & = \cos^2x - \sin^2x\\
         & = 2\cos^2x - 1\\
         & = 1 - 2\sin^2x
\end{align*}
The three identities for $\cos(2x)$ can be shown to be equivalent using the Pythagorean Identity $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$.
\begin{align*}
\cos x\cos(2x) + \sin x\sin(2x) & = \cos x(1 - 2\sin^2x) + \sin x(2\sin x\cos x)\\
& = \cos x - 2\sin^2x\cos x + 2\sin^2x\cos x\\
& = \cos x
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $\cos2x= \cos^2x-\sin^2x$ and $\sin2x= 2 \cos x \sin x$.
The simplification also can be done by :
$$\cos3x=\cos(2x+x)=\cos 2x\ cosx -\sin2x \sin x$$
Similarly for the $\sin$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the equation is the equation $\cos^{2}x + \sin^{2}x = 1$ in disguise; since
$\cos x (\cos 2x) + \sin x(\sin 2x) = \cos x$ implies that
$$\cos x(\cos^{2}x - \sin^{2}x) + \sin x(2\sin x \cos x) = \cos x,$$
so 
$$\cos^{2} x - \sin^{2} x + 2\sin^{2} x = 1,$$
that is,
$\cos^{2}x + \sin^{2}x = 1.$

Answer (score 0):

One can prove the same result by using definitions for cosine and sine functions in terms of exponential function: cos x=[e^(ix)+e^(-ix)]/2,sin x=[e^(ix)-e^(-ix)]/2 i in the right hand side and get the left hand side. I tried it and it is very straightforward.